# Get user id from the AWS cloudtrail logs

Tags: aws-lambda, amazon-iam, amazon-cloudwatch, aws-event-bridge, aws-cloudtrail

I have the lambda function, SNS topic, cloudwatch log group, cloudwatch metric filter, cloudwatch alarms in the Ireland region.

Cloudwatch metric filter triggers the cloudwatch alarm, after this cloudwatch alarm sends to SNS, then SNS triggers my lambda, and my lambda function parses json from the cloudwatch alarm, and sends me data to telegram.

Everything works great, but I have some cloudwatch metric filters with next pattern just for example ($.eventName = "CreateUser"), and I want to get user ID who did this action.

How can I do it?

The first decision is to create eventbridge rules that will trigger my lambda. It's perfect variant, but I am in the Ireland not at Virginia, and AWS docs says that  "IAM API calls are published only in the us-east-1 Region".

What I can create to get the user ID of IAM actions???

Comment: Is there a reason you can't create your rule in us-east-1? That's where all IAM events happen. You can have your rule in us-east-1 trigger something in another region.

Comment: Thx for support. The problem was solved by another way)